# How do I rig an outfit on Blender 2.78c?

Tags: blender

I have searched for a long time to find out how to get an outfit to move with the mesh without it clipping, but I cannot find a single tutorial that is not outdated, nor can I find a method that works in slight.

I have tried to use videos and applying it  in action, but they aren't the same and do not work.

I have even tried this tutorial:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76

There is nothing on rigging in 2.78.

Any help that would progress my learning would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in 2.78 that makes older rigging tutorials outdated. Rather than a general question, show an example of what you have done and ask how do I fix this? It is common to hide body parts behind clothing or only have visible body parts exist in the mesh. You  will find [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com) will be more helpful for this topic.